# Inconsistent module location in python and jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

Because of the incompatibility between the Apple's new M1 chip and TensorFlow in Python, I followed some online guides to create an environment under Miniforge3 (so that we can run the python in the arm64 instead of the x86_64 one? I don't fully understand the tricks here.).

Following the tutorial (at https://medium.com/codex/installing-tensorflow-on-m1-macs-958767a7a4b3), I created an environment named `tf` and successfully installed `tensorflow`. I checked that the modules are installed inside the `miniforge3` folder:

```
(tf) pokfung@pn-204-145 ~ % which python
/Users/pokfung/miniforge3/envs/tf/bin/python
(tf) pokfung@pn-204-145 ~ % python
Python 3.8.10 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, May 11 2021, 06:27:18) 
[Clang 11.1.0 ] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy, tensorflow
>>> print(numpy.__file__)
/Users/pokfung/miniforge3/envs/tf/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py
>>> print(tensorflow.__file__)
/Users/pokfung/miniforge3/envs/tf/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py
```

However, when I initiate the Jupyter notebook by `(tf) pokfung@pn-204-145 ~ % jupyter notebook`, I found that the notebook was not loading modules from the above directories:

```
import numpy
print(numpy.__file__)
# Output of the print statement is:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py
```

I wonder how I shall configure the Jupyter notebook so that it can correctly run in the `tf` conda environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jupyter runs a kernel in the background that in your case supports Python, but it chooses the kernel from your main installation not the virtual environment you just installed. You can [tell Jupyter which kernel to use](https://doc.cocalc.com/howto/jupyter-kernel-selection.html) - Have you tried that?

Comment: This exactly solves my problem, thank you!